# magento upgradation from 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento-1.7, upgrade, magento-1.8

We have installed magento 1.8 in dev server and added the required extensions and changed the theme and finally updated the live site database.  Now we are unable to checkout.  While checkout using Money order payment method, we got the following message in alert box

```
There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later
```

How to upgrade in this stage?

I have tried:
Renamed the local.xml and followed the installation steps of magento. But it is not working. Is the method is correct to upgrade the database from 1.7 to 1.8?

How to check whether the db is upgraded or not?

Kindly if anyone know the issue, kindly help us.

Comment: what does the error logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Check your var/log/exception.log or set

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in your index.php to get an exception trace, which should help you to pin down the file causing the error.

Comment: i have checked my exception.log - it shows no error in exception log

Comment: Is logging enabled at all?

Comment: In System-Configuration->Developer->Log Settings-> Enabled as Yes.

Comment: try this link.. might be helpful.. 
The error seems from one of your payment method ..

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/35266/